# Closed as duplicate of deleted question

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63/lord-of-the-rings-online-weaponsmithing-guide-closed) has been closed as a duplicate of a question that has been deleted. Is it still a duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the source question was deleted isn't proof that the secondary question is not a duplicate. It certainly makes it difficult to see what the similarities are, but it doesn't change the duplication of content. In some scenarios, actually, the deletion of the parent question usually implies that the duplicates should be deleted, as well.

These should probably be handled on a case-by-case basis, not with some general rule, due to the rarity in how often they should come up.

Comment: +1 to: "In some scenarios, actually, the deletion of the parent question usually implies that the duplicates should be deleted, as well."

Answer (score 2):

All of the LOTR guide questions were deleted by Jeff because they were kinda abusing the system (they were all the same except for one word)

That one remained because it had an answer. I guess it *could* (after discussion) be re-opened if you don't create the rest like last time, though you had your answer already.

Comment: That's not really answering the question.

Comment: @antony, sorry, I had the edit stuck at human verification on another tab.

Comment: I don't quite see the connection between opening that specific question and asking or not asking similar questions. Rob and I chatted and we're on the same page; I wanted to help the community, during early, closed beta, when it wasn't public, figure out if that type of question was useful: it turned out to not be(generally).

Comment: The question is useful, but having 20 of the same isn't. This has been discusses already.

Comment: The question is useful, and not a duplicate of readable content anymore. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Ardi where are the other ~20? I thought every single one 'cept the one in question had been cleaned up? ie, there is only one; is it a duplicate of itself?

Comment: I accidentally deleted the question. oops.